# Rushed In Baldur's Gate

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-enhanced

I'm new to this series, and enjoying it a ton. However I know that the in game calendar is important and I'm feeling rushed. I've already had an NPC urge me to hurry up.

How do I know when I can freely explore, and when I need to scurry to the next plot point?

Please no spoilers. I'm just finishing BG1 chapter 2

Comment: Recommend a distinct save point then seeing for yourself.  I never received these messages but am not the completionist type tho I did explore some=)

Comment: I'd thought of that, but I also don't want to be 10 hours in and realize that Drow have looted a main city because "the heroes never came".

Comment: I've only played the second one, but AFAIK these are *NPC-specific quests* (not main plot points) that you're in danger of failing. If you didn't have them in your party, you'd never get the quests anyway. But does BG1 have a *hurry up and save us* plot like Fallout 1? And just like that game, does it not really matter? Personally I doubt it; Black Isle never left us hanging ;)

Comment: Thanks Mazura! You should have posted that as a full reply so I could give you more points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main storyline does not have a deadline.

Various sidequests do have deadlines.  A number of possible party members will join you on the condition that you help them with a quest.  You should do this reasonably quickly after they join you, or they'll leave to do it themselves:

- Minsc's quest
- Coran's quest
- Eldoth's quest
- Safana's quest in the Enhanced Edition, but not in the original.
- Kivan's quest in the Enhanced Edition, but not in the original.
- Kagain's quest feels like should have a time limit, but it doesn't.  (And when you finish it, you'll find out why it doesn't.)

Every other sidequest I know of with a time limit makes it explicit (eg. "you'll be dead in a week").

Comment: Adding to this: Certain party members urge you to go to Nashkel. Jaheira and Khalid complain a lot, but never leave the party. Xzar and Montaron will leave after about 15 in-game days. But since all reaching Nashkel does is starting Chapter 2 there's really no downside to go there once and then do other quests before heading into the mines.